# Unknown multiple foreign keys to the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

So I've got a table :

```
CREATE TABLE Commande
(
id_commande int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
client_id int,
livreur_id int,
plat_id int,
dessert_id int,
prix_total int,
heure_estime time,
FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES Client(id_client),
FOREIGN KEY (livreur_id) REFERENCES Livreur(id_livreur),
FOREIGN KEY (plat_id) REFERENCES Plat(id_plat),
FOREIGN KEY (dessert_id) REFERENCES Dessert(id_dessert)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And in this table, I've got a plat_id and dessert_id, these means that each client can order a plat and a dessert, but I want it to be like each client can order multiple plat and multiple dessert and I don't know the quantity each client is going to order. How to do do this? I hope my question is explicit enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a many-to-many relationship here. You can achieve that using a 'junction table' that relates every plate to every "commande". The table would have 2 foreign keys, one to the id_commande in the commande and one to plat_id in the Plat table. Thus, if the user with id_commande 1 eats two plates (1 and 2), you will be able to reflect that by adding 2 records to that table:

```
First record: id_commande: 1, plat_id: 1
Second record: id_commande: 1, plat_id: 2
```

You can add another table to relate the commande table with dessert as well.

Comment: Since the table will relate commande with plate, you can call it something like 'COMMANDPLATE'.